# Cleanup A String from Most Simply

Tags: python, string, if-statement, for-loop, strip

What would be a short simple way to cleanup an user entered string.
Here is code I rely on while cleaning up a mess. It would be great if a shorter smarter version of it would be available.

```
invalid = ['#','@','$','$','%','^','&','*','(',')','-','+','!',' ']
for c in invalid: 
    if len(line)>0: line=line.replace(c,'')
```

PS How would I put this for (with nested if) function onto a single line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fastest way to do this is to use `str.translate`:

```
>>> invalid = ['#','@','$','$','%','^','&','*','(',')','-','+','!',' ']
>>> s = '@#$%^&*fdsfs#$%^&*FGHGJ'
>>> s.translate(None, ''.join(invalid))
'fdsfsFGHGJ'
```

**Timing comparisons**:

```
>>> s = '@#$%^&*fdsfs#$%^&*FGHGJ'*100

>>> %timeit re.sub('[#@$%^&*()-+!]', '', s)
1000 loops, best of 3: 766 µs per loop

>>> %timeit re.sub('[#@$%^&*()-+!]+', '', s)
1000 loops, best of 3: 215 µs per loop

>>> %timeit "".join(c for c in s if c not in invalid)
100 loops, best of 3: 1.29 ms per loop

>>> %timeit re.sub(invalid_re, '', s)
1000 loops, best of 3: 718 µs per loop

>>> %timeit s.translate(None, ''.join(invalid))         #Winner
10000 loops, best of 3: 17 µs per loop
```

---

On Python3 you need to do something like this:

```
>>> trans_tab = {ord(x):None for x in invalid}
>>> s.translate(trans_tab)
'fdsfsFGHGJ'
```

Answer (score 5):

```
import re
re.sub('[#@$%^&*()-+!]', '', line)
```

`re` is the regular expression module. Using square brackets means "match any one of these things inside the brackets". So the call says, "find anything in `line` inside the brackets and replace it with nothing (`''`).

Comment: By the way, if you want to clean out square brackets too, you have to escape the right-hand one: `re.sub('[#@$%^&*()-+![\]]', '', line)`.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like this:

```
from string import punctuation # !"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~

line = "".join(c for c in line if c not in punctuation)
```

For example:

```
'hello, I @m pleased to meet you! How *about (you) try something > new?'
```

becomes

```
'hello I m pleased to meet you How about you try something  new'
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one case in which a regex actually is useful.

```
>>> invalid = ['#','@','$','$','%','^','&','*','(',')','-','+','!',' ']
>>> import re
>>> invalid_re = '|'.join(map(re.escape, invalid))
>>> re.sub(invalid_re, '', 'foo * bar')
'foobar'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a snippet that I use in my own code. You're basically using regex to specify what characters are allowed, matching on those, and then concatenating them together.

```
import re

def clean(string_to_clean, valid='ACDEFGHIKLMNPQRSTVWY'):
    """Remove unwanted characters from string.

    Args:
    clean: (str) The string from which to remove
     unwanted characters.

     valid_chars: (str) The characters that are valid and should be
     included in the returned sequence. Default character
     set is: 'ACDEFGHIKLMNPQRSTVWY'.

     Returns: (str) A sequence without the invalid characters, as a string.

     """
    valid_string = r'([{}]+)'.format(valid)
    valid_regex = re.compile(valid_string, re.IGNORECASE)

    # Create string of matching characters, concatenate to string
    # with join().
    return (''.join(valid_regex.findall(string_to_clean)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a simple list comprehension:

```
>>> invalid = ['#','@','$','$','%','^','&','*','(',')','-','+','!',' ']
>>> x = 'foo * bar'
>>> "".join(i for i in x if i not in invalid)
'foobar'
```

Use list comprehension with `string.punctuation`+`\s`:

```
>>> import string
>>> x = 'foo * bar'
>>> "".join(i for i in x if i not in string.punctuation)
'foo  bar'
>>> "".join(i for i in x if i not in string.punctuation+" ")
'foobar'
```

Use `str.translate`:

```
>>> invalid = ['#','@','$','$','%','^','&','*','(',')','-','+','!',' ']
>>> x = 'foo * bar'
>>> x.translate(None,"".join(invalid))
'foobar'
```

Use `re.sub`:

```
>>> import re
>>> invalid = ['#','@','$','$','%','^','&','*','(',')','-','+','!',' ']
>>> x = 'foo * bar'
>>> y = "["+"".join(invalid)+"]"
>>> re.sub(y,'',x)
'foobar'
>>> re.sub(y+'+','',x)
'foobar'
```

Answer (score 1):

This works

```
invalid = '#@$%^_ '
line = "#master_Of^Puppets#@$%Yeah"
line = "".join([for l in line if l not in invalid])
#line will be - 'masterOfPuppetsYeah'
```